# python subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, quadratic

I currently have a class called Polynomial, The initialization looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, *termpairs):
    self.termdict = dict(termpairs)
```

I'm creating a polynomial by making the keys the exponents and
the associated values are the coefficients. To create an instance of this class, you enter as follows:

```
d1 = Polynomial((5,1), (3,-4), (2,10))
```

which makes a dictionary like so:

```
{2: 10, 3: -4, 5: 1}
```

Now, I want to create a subclass of the Polynomial class called Quadratic. I want to call the Polynomial class constructor in the Quadratic class constructor, however im not quite sure how to do that. What I have tried is:

```
class Quadratic(Polynomial):
def __init__(self, quadratic, linear, constant):
    Polynomial.__init__(self, quadratic[2], linear[1], constant[0])
```

but I get errors, anyone have any tips? I feel like I'm using incorrect parameters when I call the Polynomial class constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want

```
class Quadratic(Polynomial):
    def __init__(self, quadratic, linear, constant):
        Polynomial.__init__(self, (2, quadratic), (1, linear), (0, constant))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I just put the numbers in the wrong place.

Answer (score 15):

You should also use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) instead of using the constructor directly.

```
class Quadratic(Polynomial):
    def __init__(self, quadratic, linear, constant):
       super(Quadratic, self).__init__(quadratic[2], linear[1], constant[0])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is better?

Comment: Got it. See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods