# python dictionary creation

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class called Polynomial, and it stores information to the polynomial in a dictionary. The keys are the exponents and the values are the coefficients. To create an instance of the Polynomial class, you type the following:

```
P1 = Polynomial((2, 14), (2, 11), (-12, 3), (42, 0))
```

The first item in the pairing is the coefficient, and the second item is the exponent.

The initialization looks like this:

```
class Polynomial:
def __init__(self, *termpairs):
    termdict = dict(termpairs)
    self.termdict = {}
    for x, y in termdict.items():
        self.termdict[y] = x
```

Now if I have two coefficients that are the same, for example ((2, 14), (2, 11)), It will only create a dictionary for one of them like so:

```
{11: 2}
```

Im not sure why the one pairing is not showing up. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have the exponent/coefficient pairs properly matched to key/value pairs when you posted two days ago.  What happened?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290323/python-subclasses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
termdict = dict(termpairs)
```

You are "converting" your `termpairs` to a dict, so you will get something like:

```
((2, 14), (2, 11), (-12, 3), (42, 0)) => {2: 14, 2: 11, -12: 3, 42: 0}
```

In a `dict` there cannot be two items with the same key, so the second one (`2: 11`) is overwriting the first one (`2: 14`).

**EDIT:** Why are you converting it to a `dict` anyway? This would be a simpler solution (with no `dict` conversion):

```
def __init__(self, *termpairs):
    self.termdict = {}
    # termpairs is a tuple of tuples
    for x, y in termdict:
        self.termdict[y] = x
```

Comment: There's no casting going on there.

Comment: Yea that was it. I really don't know why I made a new dictionary, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kindall: I know casting is not the word, but I can't figure out a better one, suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary has one value per key. What would `self.termdict[11]` return otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Because your dictionary `termdict` (not `self.termdict`) maps *coefficients* to *powers*, then the same coefficient forces only the second one to be used (i.e., `(2, 11)` erases `(2, 14)`). Instead, you want to replace your class with:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, *termpairs):
        termdict = dict([ (b, a) for a, b in termpairs ])
        self.termdict = {}
        for x, y in termdict.items():
            self.termdict[x] = y
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your culprit:

```
termdict = dict(termpairs)
```

This creates a dictionary where the keys are the coefficients and the values are the exponents. Since it's a dictionary, each key points to one value, so at this point you lose the `(2, 14)` pair -- there can't be more than one item with the key `2`. That you then proceed to switch 'em around makes no difference; you've already dropped some data on the floor.

I'm not sure why you're putting them in a dictionary to begin with, and then iterating over that to make a second dictionary. Why not just put them in the way you want to begin with?

```
self.termdict = dict(reversed(pair) for pair in termpairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the older values each time you add to the dictionary, you need to do something such as adding the values into a list and storing that list as the value.

the dictionary structure would look like:

`{ 2:[14,11], -12:[3], 42:[0] }`
and will allow you to store multiple pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the `termdict` dictionary, just iterate over the items of the tuple (untested):

```
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, *termpairs):
        self.termdict = {}
        for x, y in termpairs:
            self.termdict[y] = x
```